# Unable to access my MAC keychain due to this

Tags: macos, keychain

PLEASE FORGIVE ME IF THIS IS NOT A RELATED QUESTION. (this is of top priority)

Recently i tried to change the home folder name of my mac mini. i have gone through a website and followed some instructions to do that. finally i have ended up by creating a completely new user profile with a new home folder name. 
after some time i have decide to turn back to my old user and deleted the recently created user. 
This is where all my problems started. Now my deleted user folder is in my hardisk with the the follwing name - alpha(deleted). This folder is still being treated as my home folder even after logging in from a different user. I am unable to access even my keychain services through mac. Some softwares are asking me to reinstall on this user.... i ran into chaos with this. 
Can some one help me to make my current user as default and renew my keychain access... Please help me as this is of high priority for me..
Thank you

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should be migrated to apple.stackexchange.com, but you need to go into the newly created account in System Preferences Users pane and change the home folder manually, you may have skipped this step. Usually they will tell you to simply rename your old home folder and set it as the  home folder for the new user or simply just rename your home folder and set it as the home folder for the current user.

Comment: hi ramos, but i no longer have my newly created home folder because i have deleted it completely from my system

Comment: I guess the guide you followed wasn't very good as your home folder contains the key for your keychain

Comment: i am completely new to this mac and i did that in a bit of hurry... Is there any way out of this?

Comment: not unless you can get your home folder back, im pretty sure there were plenty of warnings during the process though, changing your short name in mac is somewhat more complicated than standard unix systems because the home folder in mac is very coupled to everything

Comment: ooh... so, cant i make my current user as default user and recreate my keychain???

Comment: yeah, you just won't have the information from your old keychain

Comment: Actually i am an iphone apps developer. Now i am unable to load my app into the device through my Adhoc certificate. i get a code signing error.. i think this is because of the keychain. is there any way i can do it ramos???

Comment: I suggest trying to load it on a clean user account and see what happens, I can't remember if the keychain for an account contains the key for your dev license.